# Un origen y significados muy pipiripaos

Tags: etimología, significado

Hoy por circunstancias laborales recordaba la palabra *pipiripao* y consultando el diccionario, me doy cuenta que tiene ya un buen rato en el idioma español e incluso ya aparece como obsoleta a este lado del Atlántico... pero vamos poco a poco. En el mapa de diccionarios aparece desde 1780 con un significado similar al del diccionario actual:

> [**pipiripao**](https://dle.rae.es/pipiripao)
>   1. m. coloq. Convite espléndido y magnífico, especialmente el que forma parte de una serie de ellos que se van haciendo un día en una casa y otro en otra.

Sin embargo, al cruzar el océano gracias al Damer nos dicen:

> [**pipiripao**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=Pm8SNMy2kx0AcijLott) adj. Ni. Referido a cosa, de poco valor.
>    **de ~**. loc. adj. Mx, Gu, Ni, CR, RD; Co, obsol. De poca calidad a pesar de su buena apariencia. desp. (de pipiripiao).

Tenemos significados bastante diferentes de un lado en varios países... (Referenciada en la zona caribeña de una forma diferente). Pero no es lo único, al revisar el CORDE y en Google Ngrams, la palabra aparece en textos solo desde la mitad del siglo XIX (de 1850), casi 70 años de la primera edición del DRAE. Además, en el CORDE a fines del siglo XIX ya aparece la expresión *de pipiripao* con el significado del Diccionario de Americanismos en un texto peruano (lo que da a entender que se conocía la expresión en la zona). Si bien lo más probable es que haya tomado un significado de corte irónico o sarcástico (estoy especulando) no ayuda mucho la etimología de la palabra ya que no se menciona ninguna en el DLE.

Así pues, ¿Cuál es el origen de esta palabra y sus significados con antonimia?

Answer (score 2):

En el NTLLE puedes ver que ya aparece en el DRAE en 1737, e indica que "es voz baxa" y en el ejemplo que cita se indica " ... no es Castellana esa voz ..."

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugiero que complementes un poco tu respuesta con el posible origen de la palabra (Si no es castellana, entonces ¿de qué lengua viene? ¿existe en otra lengua romance acaso?)